# InvalidParameterCombination: "Duplicate tag key found in request" for Amazon Neptune Service CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-neptune

When I deploy my CloudFormation Stack, I receive the following error:

> Duplicate tag key found in request: Name (Service: AmazonNeptune;
> Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID:
> ffffc8f8-ac83-4eb0-8794-47c6f5ff5ed1; Proxy: null)

This error only happens when I deploy with multiple stack templates. If I deploy the template that fails (the sub-child stack) on its own, then it will succeed. It only fails when this stack is a child of my other templates.

There are multiple layers. I have the root stack with multiple child stacks(one of which is `neptune-application-map.yaml`), and then I have a sub-child stack (`neptune.yaml` which is a NeptuneStack resource). The sub-child stack is the failing one.

Please note, that this error happens for multiple Resources within the failing stack (this sub-child stack). The resources that this error occurs on are:

- NeptuneDBClusterParameterGroup
- NeptuneDBParameterGroup
- NeptuneSubnetGroup

Since there are optional, I tried to remove them, but then got the same error again for `NeptuneDBCluster` Resource within the same sub-child stack.

Here, I am attaching yaml for reference.

`neptune-application-map.yaml`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Neptune full stack with gremlin and rd4j console
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: dev/staging/prod
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: ["dev", "staging", "prod"]
    MaxLength: 15
  
  SubnetIds:
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
    Description: Neptune VPC Subnets

  DefaultSecurityGroupId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
  
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id

  DbInstanceType:
    Description: Neptune DB instance type
    Type: String
    Default: db.r5.large
    AllowedValues:
      - db.t3.medium
      - db.r4.large
      - db.r4.xlarge
      - db.r4.2xlarge
      - db.r4.4xlarge
      - db.r4.8xlarge
      - db.r5.large
      - db.r5.xlarge
      - db.r5.2xlarge
      - db.r5.4xlarge
      - db.r5.8xlarge
      - db.r5.12xlarge
    ConstraintDescription: >-
      Must be a valid Neptune instance type. Note that for Stockholm and OSU
      only R5 and T3 instances are available.

  DBReplicaIdentifierSuffix:
    Description: >-
      OPTIONAL: The ID for the Neptune Replica to use. Empty means no read
      replica.
    Type: String
    Default: ''
  
  DBClusterPort:
    Type: String
    Default: '8182'
    Description: Enter the port of your Neptune cluster
  
  EC2ClientInstanceType:
    Description: EC2 client instance
    Type: String
    Default: r5.2xlarge # t3.medium
    AllowedValues:
      - t3.micro
      - t3.small
      - t3.medium
      - m5.large
      - m5.xlarge
      - m5.2xlarge
      - m5.4xlarge
      - m5.12xlarge
      - r4.large
      - r4.xlarge
      - r4.2xlarge
      - r4.4xlarge
      - r4.8xlarge
      - r5.large
      - r5.xlarge
      - r5.2xlarge
      - r5.4xlarge
      - r5.12xlarge
    ConstraintDescription: >-
      Must be a valid EC2 instance type. Note some regions support limited
      instance types only. Ex: Stockholm and OSU does not support R4 instances
  
  NeptuneQueryTimeout:
    Type: Number
    Default: 20000
    Description: Neptune Query Time out (in milliseconds)
  
  NeptuneEnableAuditLog:
    Type: Number
    Default: 0
    AllowedValues:
      - 0
      - 1
    Description: Enable Audit Log. 0 means disable and 1 means enable.
  
  IamAuthEnabled:
    Type: String
    Default: 'false'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'true'
      - 'false'
    Description: Enable IAM Auth for Neptune.
  
  SetupGremlinConsole:
    Type: String
    Default: 'true'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'true'
      - 'false'
    Description: Setup Gremlin console.
  
  SetupRDF4JConsole:
    Type: String
    Default: 'true'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'true'
      - 'false'
    Description: Setup RDF4J console.
  
  AttachBulkloadIAMRoleToNeptuneCluster:
    Type: String
    Default: 'true'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'true'
      - 'false'
    Description: Attach Bulkload IAM role to cluster
  
  NotebookInstanceType:
    Description: >-
      SageMaker Notebook instance type. Please refer
      https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/ for uptodate allowed instance
      type in aws region and https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/pricing/ for
      pricing.
    Type: String
    Default: none
    AllowedValues:
      - none
      - ml.t2.medium
      - ml.t2.large
      - ml.t2.xlarge
      - ml.t2.2xlarge
      - ml.m4.xlarge
      - ml.m4.2xlarge
      - ml.m4.4xlarge
      - ml.m4.10xlarge
      - ml.m4.16xlarge
      - ml.m5.large
      - ml.m5.xlarge
      - ml.m5.2xlarge
      - ml.m5.4xlarge
      - ml.m5.12xlarge
      - ml.m5.24xlarge
      - ml.m5d.large
      - ml.m5d.xlarge
      - ml.m5d.2xlarge
      - ml.m5d.4xlarge
      - ml.m5d.12xlarge
      - ml.m5d.24xlarge
      - ml.c4.large
      - ml.c4.xlarge
      - ml.c4.2xlarge
      - ml.c4.4xlarge
      - ml.c4.8xlarge
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid SageMaker instance type.
  NeptuneSagemakerNotebookStartupScript:
    Description: 'OPTIONAL: Startup script additions for the notebook instance.'
    Type: String
    Default: ''
  S3BucketPrefix:
    Type: String
    Default: 'binxio-public'
  
  CFNCustomProviderZipFileName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'lambdas/cfn-secret-provider-1.3.1.zip'
Rules:
  DBInstanceTypeVsRegion:
    RuleCondition: !Or
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - eu-north-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - us-gov-east-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - ca-central-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - me-south-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - cn-northwest-1
    Assertions:
      - Assert:
          'Fn::Contains':
            - - db.t3.medium
              - db.r5.large
              - db.r5.xlarge
              - db.r5.2xlarge
              - db.r5.4xlarge
              - db.r5.12xlarge
            - !Ref DbInstanceType
        AssertDescription: >-
          Only R5 and T3 Instances are available in eu-north-1 (ARN),
          us-gov-east-1 (OSU), ca-central-1 (YUL), me-south-1 (BAH) and
          cn-northwest-1 (ZHY)
  EC2ClientInstanceTypeVsRegion:
    RuleCondition: !Or
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - eu-north-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - us-gov-east-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - ca-central-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - me-south-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - cn-northwest-1
    Assertions:
      - Assert: !Not
          - 'Fn::Contains':
              - - r4.large
                - r4.xlarge
                - r4.2xlarge
                - r4.4xlarge
                - r4.8xlarge
              - !Ref EC2ClientInstanceType
        AssertDescription: >-
          R4 Instances are not available in eu-north-1 (ARN), us-gov-east-1
          (OSU), ca-central-1 (YUL), me-south-1 (BAH) and cn-northwest-1 (ZHY)
  SagemakerNotebookInstanceTypeVsRegion:
    RuleCondition: !Or
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - us-gov-east-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - us-gov-west-1
      - !Equals
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - cn-northwest-1
    Assertions:
      - Assert:
          'Fn::Contains':
            - - none
            - !Ref NotebookInstanceType
        AssertDescription: >-
          Neptune Sagemaker notebooks are not available in us-gov-east-1 (OSU),
          us-gov-west-1 (PDT) and cn-northwest-1 (ZHY)
Conditions:
  CreateDBReplicaInstance: !Not
    - !Equals
      - !Ref DBReplicaIdentifierSuffix
      - ''
  AZ3NotPresent: !Equals
    - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
    - ca-central-1
  AZ3Present: !Not
    - !Condition AZ3NotPresent
  CreateSagemakerNotebook: !Equals
    - !Ref NotebookInstanceType
    - none
Resources:
  CFNSecretProvider:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: cfn-secret-provider-1.3.1.yaml
      Parameters:
        S3BucketPrefix: !Ref S3BucketPrefix
        CFNCustomProviderZipFileName: !Ref CFNCustomProviderZipFileName
        Environment: !Ref Environment
  PrivateKey:
    Type: Custom::RSAKey
    DependsOn: CFNSecretProvider
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '/${Environment}-${AWS::Region}/neptune-stack/private-key'
      Version: v1
      NoEcho: False
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt [ CFNSecretProvider, Outputs.LambdaArn ]
  EC2CustomKeyPair:
    Type: Custom::KeyPair
    DependsOn: [ PrivateKey, CFNSecretProvider ]
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${Environment}-${AWS::Region}-custom-key-pair'
      NoEcho: False
      PublicKeyMaterial: !GetAtt 'PrivateKey.PublicKey'
      ServiceToken:  !GetAtt [ CFNSecretProvider, Outputs.LambdaArn ]
  NeptuneStack:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    DependsOn: [ EC2CustomKeyPair, CFNSecretProvider ]
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: neptune.yaml
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      Parameters:
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DBClusterPort: !Ref DBClusterPort
        DbInstanceType: !Ref DbInstanceType
        NeptuneQueryTimeout: !Ref NeptuneQueryTimeout
        NeptuneEnableAuditLog: !Ref NeptuneEnableAuditLog
        IamAuthEnabled: !Ref IamAuthEnabled
        SubnetIds: !Join [ ",", !Ref SubnetIds ]
        DefaultSecurityGroupId: !Ref DefaultSecurityGroupId
        VpcId: !Ref VpcId

  NeptuneEC2Client:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    DependsOn: EC2CustomKeyPair
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Join
        - ''
        - - >-
            https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-neptune-customer-samples/v2/cloudformation-templates/neptune-ec2-client.json
      TimeoutInMinutes: 30
      Parameters:
        Env: !Ref Environment
        EC2SSHKeyPairName: !Sub '${Environment}-${AWS::Region}-custom-key-pair'
        EC2ClientInstanceType: !Ref EC2ClientInstanceType
        SetupGremlinConsole: !Ref SetupGremlinConsole
        SetupRDF4JConsole: !Ref SetupRDF4JConsole
        AttachBulkloadIAMRoleToNeptuneCluster: !Ref AttachBulkloadIAMRoleToNeptuneCluster
        VPC: !Ref VpcId
        Subnet: !Select [0, !Ref SubnetIds]
        NeptuneDBCluster: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.DBClusterId
        NeptuneDBClusterEndpoint: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.DBClusterEndpoint
        NeptuneDBClusterPort: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.DBClusterPort
        NeptuneLoadFromS3IAMRoleArn: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.NeptuneLoadFromS3IAMRoleArn
        NeptuneSG: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.NeptuneSecurityGroup
        NeptuneEC2InstanceProfile: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.NeptuneEC2InstanceProfile
  NeptuneSagemakerNotebook:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    Condition: CreateSagemakerNotebook
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Join
        - ''
        - - >-
            https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-neptune-customer-samples/v2/cloudformation-templates/neptune-sagemaker-notebook-stack.json
      TimeoutInMinutes: 30
      Parameters:
        Env: !Ref Environment
        NotebookInstanceType: !Ref NotebookInstanceType
        NeptuneClusterEndpoint: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.DBClusterEndpoint
        NeptuneClusterPort: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.DBClusterPort
        NeptuneClusterVpc: !Ref VpcId
        NeptuneClusterSubnetId: !Select [0, !Ref SubnetIds]
        NeptuneClientSecurityGroup: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.NeptuneSecurityGroup
        NeptuneLoadFromS3RoleArn: !GetAtt
          - NeptuneStack
          - Outputs.NeptuneLoadFromS3IAMRoleArn
        StartupScript: !Ref NeptuneSagemakerNotebookStartupScript
Outputs:
  DBClusterId:
    Description: Neptune Cluster Identifier
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.DBClusterId
  DBSubnetGroupId:
    Description: Neptune DBSubnetGroup Identifier
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.DBSubnetGroupId
  DBClusterResourceId:
    Description: Neptune Cluster Resource Identifier
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.DBClusterResourceId
  DBClusterEndpoint:
    Description: Master Endpoint for Neptune Cluster
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.DBClusterEndpoint
  DBInstanceEndpoint:
    Description: Master Instance Endpoint
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.DBInstanceEndpoint
  SparqlEndpoint:
    Description: Sparql Endpoint for Neptune
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.SparqlEndpoint
  GremlinEndpoint:
    Description: Gremlin Endpoint for Neptune
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.GremlinEndpoint
  LoaderEndpoint:
    Description: Loader Endpoint for Neptune
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.LoaderEndpoint
  DBClusterReadEndpoint:
    Description: DB cluster Read Endpoint
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.DBClusterReadEndpoint
  DBClusterPort:
    Description: Port for the Neptune Cluster
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.DBClusterPort
  NeptuneLoadFromS3IAMRoleArn:
    Description: IAM Role for loading data in Neptune
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.NeptuneLoadFromS3IAMRoleArn
  NeptuneIamAuthUser:
    Description: IAM User for IAM Auth
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneStack
      - Outputs.NeptuneIamAuthUser
  EC2Client:
    Description: EC2 client Identifier
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneEC2Client
      - Outputs.EC2Client
  SSHAccess:
    Description: This is how you gain remote access to the EC2 client.
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneEC2Client
      - Outputs.SSHAccess
  VpcId:
    Description: VPC Id
    Value: !Ref VpcId
  NeptuneSagemakerNotebook:
    Condition: CreateSagemakerNotebook
    Description: Neptune Sagemaker Notebook Name
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneSagemakerNotebook
      - Outputs.NeptuneSagemakerNotebook
  NeptuneNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigId:
    Condition: CreateSagemakerNotebook
    Description: Neptune Sagemaker Notebook Instance Lifecycle ConfigId
    Value: !GetAtt
      - NeptuneSagemakerNotebook
      - Outputs.NeptuneNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigId
  NeptuneSecurityGroup:
    Value: !GetAtt NeptuneStack.Outputs.NeptuneSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: !Sub 'NeptuneSecurityGroup-NeptuneStack'
  PublicKey:
    Value: !GetAtt 'PrivateKey.PublicKey'
    Description: the public key, safe to expose
  PrivateKeyArn:
    Value: !GetAtt 'PrivateKey.Arn'
    Description: ARN of the private key in the Parameter Stor
```

`neptune.yaml`

https://gist.github.com/luzan/073fcbe9bc2980b59d09606a4dcdb75d

*Posting it as link because of character limit on SO.*

There are more, but there are the involved stacks that fail. Let me know if you need more for reference.

Comment: One thing is that you have Description as a property on the DBSubnetGroup, it should be DBSubnetGroupDescription though.

Comment: I actually tested with `DBSubnetGroupDescription`. Its same error.

Comment: What happens when you eliminate all the "Name" tags and deploy.

Comment: @CoinGraham I just saw your answer, i was able to fixed it after removing all the Tags in multiple resources within neptune.yaml.

Comment: You should be able to add back the tags other than "Name", perhaps it's reserved when using stacksets.

Comment: The reason is `cloudformation deploy` tags don't try to propagate stack tags to resources that support it and don't merge properly, so if you've already tagged the resources it will throw this error.